# Basic Arduino serial communication

Tags: arduino

I'm just trying to get the very basics of serial communication started; I'm trying to use this example I found, from what I understand it should be working. I just want what I type into the serial monitor to be output back, so I can see how it works. I also tried removing the while *serial.available* in case the serial monitor doesn't trigger that condition.

Here is my code:

```
// Buffer to store incoming commands from serial port
String inData;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Initialized\n");
}

void loop() {

    while (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        char received = Serial.read();
        inData += received;

        // Process message when new line character is received
        if (received == '\n')
        {
            Serial.println("Arduino Received: ");
            Serial.println(inData);

            inData = ""; // Clear received buffer
        }
    }
}
```

It currently uploads fine, and prints "initialized", but it doesn't work if I try to "send" any data.

Comment: Have you tried just printing `received` as soon as you read it?

Answer (score 1):

`Serial.read()` returns an `int`.

You need to cast to `(char)` in order to store it as a char.

```
char received = (char)Serial.read();
```

Maybe you are never receiving any data for some reason.

Let's try something super simple. Use serialEvent() as suggested [by sohnryang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913390/basic-arduino-serial-communication/34938212#34938212) and then print some text as soon as `Serial.available()` triggers:

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("Something has been received");
}
```

You should see this message every time you send something to Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Use SerialEvent. So the code will look like this.

```
String inData;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Initialized\n");
}

void loop() {
}

void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
        inData += inChar;
        if (inChar == '\n') {
            Serial.println("Arduino Recieved : ");
            Serial.println("inData");
            inData = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: serialEvent() is ***line-oriented*** (not very clear in the documentation, absent in the code comments, and misleading in the example code). That is, a newline (whatever that is. ASCII 13?) is required before serialEvent is called. The canonical is *[Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013619/)*